# error with react script rendering script tag in the body

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am trying to render a react component but instead what i get is a script tag in my body here are my code can someone help me pls when i try to render i get the below response

```js
var App =  React.Component({
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});




var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, function(Root, state) {
    React.render(<Root location={state.path}/>, document.body)
});
```

```html
<html><head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body><script data-reactid=".0"></script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Could you paste the error?

Answer (score 1):

I am pressuming you are using React 0.13.x, since you are not using ReactDOM.render. Also, I am pressuming you are using ReactRouter < V1.0.0, since you are not using the router as a jsx element.

To fix your issue, change:

```
var App =  React.Component({
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

To:

```
var App =  React.createClass({
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>App</h1>
                <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle:
[React + ReactRouter example](http://jsfiddle.net/omerts/d2mnwqLj/36/)